# Set of five consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that in any set of five consecutive integers there exists a number not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

I thought of doing a proof by contradiction. That is, suppose that each number is either a multiple of $2$ or $3$. How do we arrive at a contradiction from here?

Comment: Consider the remainder of the numbers after division by $6$. And, incidentally, you only need four consecutive integers.

Comment: We must have $0,1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4,5;2,3,4,5,0; 3,4,5,0,1; 4,5,0,1,2; 5,0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Yep. And which of those will be divisible by 2, and which by 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of any *four* consecutive integers, two are even and two are odd. Only at most one of the odd numbers can be divisible by 3. $\square$

Comment: It also is interesting that this number, say $n$, must be coprime to the other four numbers in the set. Why is that?

Comment: Not divisible by $2$ or $3$ and we know that no larger prime number divides more than one of the set.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ is coprime to $2,3$ $\iff$ $n$ is coprime to $6$ $\iff$ $\,n\equiv 1$ or $5\pmod 6.\,$ Consecutive integers correspond to consecutive residues in the cycle $\,0,1,2,3,4,5\pmod 6,\,$ Since $\,1\,$ and $\,5\,$ are at most $4$ apart in the cycle, any sequence of $4$  or more consecutive integers has an $\,n\equiv 1$ or $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Write down five consecutive numbers, like so:$$n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4$$
There are two different possible patterns for which of these are divisible by two, and which ones are not (either $n,n+2,n+4$ are divisible by $2$ and $n+1,n+3$ are not, or the other way around). There are three different patterns for divisibility by $3$.

That makes a total of six different patterns combined. You can check them all within a minute or two and see that indeed, no matter which of the pattern combinations you choose, there is always one or two numbers that are divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be a five consecutive integers, if $a,c,e$ are even then $b,d$ are odd, and if $a,c,e$ are odd then $b,d$ are even.

Case 1: $a,c,e\equiv 0\pmod 2$ then $b=a+1$ and $d=a+3$

$\implies b\equiv 1\pmod 2 \implies b\nmid 2$

$\implies d\equiv 1\pmod 2 \implies d\nmid 2$

- if $b\mid 3$ then $b\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $d=b+2\implies d\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

$d\nmid 2,d\nmid 3$

- if $d\mid 3$ then $d\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $b=d-2\implies b\equiv 1\pmod 3$

$b\nmid2,b\nmid 3$

do the same for case 2: $a,c,e$ are odd and $b,d$ are even.